# Uncaught Error: Class 'LinePlot' not found

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am trying to make a line graph in JpGraph and when I copy the official code from [here](https://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_line1.php) it returns the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'LinePlot' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/graph/official.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/graph/official.php on line 34
```

This also happens for other line graphs that I try to do when it mentions the new LinePlot in code. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you included both of these

```
require_once "jpgraph.php";
require_once "jpgraph_line.php";
```

Thats what was missing for me.